# How to define a generic abstract class that inherits a generic abstract class?

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I have a class that inherits an abstract class which inherits another abstract class. I can define the most-super class as being generic just fine, but I don't know how to define the middle class as being generic before I express the actual type I want in the final `ListResults` class.

```
internal abstract class LowerCommand<T> {
    public abstract void Execute();
    public abstract List<T> ExecuteList();
}

// currently gives error for `T`
internal abstract class HigherCommand : Lowercommand<T> {
    // ... defines other stuff, nothing to do with
    //     already instantiated methods or T ...
}

class ListResults : HigherCommand<Results>
{
    public override void Execute() {...}
    public override List<Results> ExecuteList() {...}
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `internal abstract class HigherCommand<T>`?

Comment: You should take the time to read the error messages that the compiler gives you, and specially take the time to follow the link to the help page that Visual Studio provides.

Comment: You have to define `T` in the `HigherCommand` signature so it can be passed in by the user: `HigherCommand<T>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need to define the generic type parameter `T` on the definition of `HigherCommand` so it can in turn properly define `LowerCommand`.

```
internal abstract class LowerCommand<T> {
    public abstract void Execute();
    public abstract List<T> ExecuteList();
}

// Note that HigherCommand require a declaration of `T`
internal abstract class HigherCommand<T> : LowerCommand<T> {
    // ... defines other stuff, nothing to do with
    //     already instantiated methods or T ...
}

class ListResults : HigherCommand<Results>
{
    public override void Execute() {...}
    public override List<Results> ExecuteList() {...}
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Sorry, I started C# yesterday and I've kinda just been searching this stuff as I go.